# How can I make a text file in git-bash?

Tags: git, text, text-files, git-bash

How can I make a text file in Git-bash and then how do I go into that file and add text?

Answer (score 18):

There are many ways to create a file using BASH.

using touch `touch newFile.txt` only creates.
using echo `echo > newFile.txt`  only creates.
using cat `cat > newFile.txt` creates and can start appending to file.
using vim `vim newFile.txt` creates and can start editing the file.

Also the .txt extension is only for convenience and categorization. Some editors view the extension to format the data, but for a `txt` there's no differnce.

After creating the file, add it to the git repository.

`git add newFile.txt`
`git commit -m "added new file"`

Comment: commit is with double `m` :)

Comment: Using `cat` on a file which doesn't exist will result in an error.

Comment: @ SVTAnthony, please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40632531/can-a-new-file-be-created-in-git-with-an-existing-file-already-on-local-machine

Comment: the `cat> newFile.txt` option, how to commit it?

Comment: @Berkay it is `CTRL` + d but it is overriding the file, not appending or showing the content. when you open vit `cat` and exit with `CTRL`+d  the existing content is vanishing

Answer (score 5):

You can use the echo command. Enter the following line into your command prompt to create a new file with the required content:

```
echo "Put any content here" >> Newfile.txt
```

If the command line doesn't return any message, this means that you created the file correctly.

The message in between the double quotes will be the content of the new file.

Answer (score 1):

In bash alone, you can simple use echo (to initialize it) and **[`vi`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi)** (to edit it)

```
echo Text example> aNewFile.txt
vi aNewFile.txt
git add aNewFile.txt
git commit -m "Add aNewFile.txt"
```

Depending on your environment, you can [setup other editors](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup#Your-Editor), but in a Windows Git bash, `vi` is the default one.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using git bash (or terminal under unix/mac) you simply have to type `echo 'text...' >> file_name`.

if you are no windows machine and you try to do it from cmd its much better to simply create the file with windows explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to open a new text file

```
subl newFile.txt
```

Here `subl` represents sublime text, my default text editor, and `newFile.txt` is the new file I want to create and edit. git-bash opens the new file in you default text editor. You can edit and save from there, or just save

To add the new file to `stage` use this code

```
git add newFile.txt
```

ant to `commit` to your reposiory, use this code

```
git commit
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all open the folder you want to create the new file in your text editor like 'brackets' or 'VS studio'.
2. Then simply type `touch newFile.txt` in `git-bash`.
3. Then go back to text editor you have previously open and you can see the `newFile.txt` appears in the open folder.

Then you can easily edit that file inside your text editor.