# Can a new file be created in Git with an existing file already on local machine

Tags: git, bitbucket

I can creat a new file in Git with the echo command:`echo > newFile.txt`
After the file is created, i just usually navigate to the file directory from file explorer, update it with my codes and save it. It works okay.

The questiion is: If i already have a file containig all my codes in a workspace on my local machine, is there a way to tell Git to create a new file using that existing file instead of manually going to edit the new Git file? I think maybe it's possible to specify the existinng file path so that Git can go to fetch it?

Comment: Copy paste? Git is not about creating files. Git is about versioning them.

Comment: Do you have a git repository or not?

Comment: @Ivan, yes I have a Git repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run [`git init`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init) from the directory where the files live. This creates a repository for your code.

You can then `git add` and `git commit` your files.

Following that, add an `origin` pointing to BitBucket so you can push your code.

`git remote add origin git@bitbucket/path/bitbucket/gives/you/for/your/repo`

`git push -u origin master` will create the master branch on the remote for the first time.

Comment: I tried git init and got a message :Initialized empty Git repository in C:/myfilepath/.git/ but looking in the specified directory, no repo was present. Have I missed something?

Comment: Run git status and see what it says.

Answer (score 0):

Git is not about backing up files. It's about maintaining versioning of files/source. First thing is you need to have git repository. Seems like you already have source in a folder. Refer : https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/ to see how you can add it to GitHub (or any other Git repository you prefer). And now when you have the new file inside this folder do a `git status`. It should show if the file exists and if it is being tracked. Please follow : http://media.pragprog.com/titles/tsgit/chap-005-extract.html for more information. Then you can proceed to `add` the file, `commit` and `push`.